# Substituir palavras

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber como eu compacto as linhas de um txt. Por exemplo as linhas estão quebradas por `\n` mas ainda fazem parte da mesma sentença.

```
SOCIAL HISTORY:Denies tobacco or alcohol use.   
PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: 
VITAL SIGNS: Age 34, blood pressure 128/78, pulse 70, temperature is 97.8,
weight is 207 pounds, and height is 5 feet 7 inches.  
GENERAL: The patient is healthy appearing; alert and oriented to person, place
and time; responds appropriately; in no acute distress.  
HEAD: Normocephalic. No masses or lesions noted.  
FACE: No facial tenderness or asymmetry noted.
```

ou blocos inteiros de texto como:

```
A complete refractive work-up was performed today, in which we found a mild
change in her distance correction, which allowed her the ability to see 20/70
in the right eye and 20/200 in the left eye. With a pair of +4 reading
glasses, she was able to read 0.5M print quite nicely. I have loaned her a
pair of +4 reading glasses at this time and we have started her with fine-
detailed reading. She will return to our office in a matter of two weeks and
we will make a better determination on what near reading glasses to prescribe
for her. I think that she is an excellent candidate for low vision help. I am
sure that we can be of great help to her in the near future.
```

que eu queria que ficassem em uma linha só.

Eu preciso que cada linha corresponda a sua identificação como por exemplo  `IDENTIFICACAO: SENTENÇA SEM QUEBRA DE LINHA`
`IDENTIFICACAO: SENTENÇA SEM QUEBRA DE LINHA`
Afim de que cada identificação fique em uma linha apenas. 
as palavras são diferentes por isso não da pra usar o `replace`.
Outro ploblema é que tem arquivos `txt` que nao estão quebrados:
`IDENTIFICACAO: SENTENÇA SEM QUEBRA DE LINHA. IDENTIFICACAO: SENTENÇA SEM QUEBRA DE LINHA. IDENTIFICACAO: SENTENÇA SEM QUEBRA DE LINHA`
Eu estava usando regex mas não esta funcionando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, acho que percebi, segundo o exemplo que colocou na pergunta pode procurar por a expressão que está maiúscula e se existem ':' na linha.

```
with open('tests.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
    lines = (i.strip() for i in f.readlines())
    text = ''
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        if(len(words) > 0):
            if(words[0].isupper() and ':' in line):
                text += '\n{}'.format(line)
                continue
            text += line
```

Aqui a variável que armazena o texto final é a `text`

Aqui está outra maneira de fazer. Primeiro vemos se existem ":" na linha, separamos a linha pelos ":" e verificamos se a expressão que vem antes dos ":" é maiuscula:

```
with open('tests.txt', 'r') as f: # abrir e ler o ficheiro
    lines = (i.strip() for i in f.readlines()) # retirar todas as quebras de linha
    text = ''
    for line in lines:
        if(':' in line):
            expression = line.split(':')[0] # separar e ficar com o que vem antes dos ":", expression
            if(expression.isupper()): # ver se e maiuscula
                text += '\n{}'.format(line)
                continue
        text += line
```

Comment: O primeiro código deu o seguinte erro:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/PEPS/ClassCrawlerPEP1.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.lista = self.arrumaDadosPEP('/mtsamples/1.txt','/Angelica/PEPS/teste/')
  File "/Angelica/PEPS/ClassCrawlerPEP1.py", line 78, in arrumaDadosPEP
    if(words[0].isupper() and ':' in line):
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Ja usei com o meu ficheiro. Acho que o outro funcionou dando mais uma olhada aqui só um minuto

Comment: Já corrigi o primeiro exemplo para não dar o mesmo erro @user2535338 , mas acho que gosto mais do segundo

Comment: Agora eu preciso tirar esses números 1\\. 2\\. .... agora da pra fazer  isso com o text.replace('num\\','')

Comment: Não percebi bem, acho melhor colocar outra pergunta @user2535338, para perceber melhor, deixando-a clara. Eu ainda vou estar aqui um bocado, talvez o consiga ajudar